# ARMA invertibility vs invertibility of AR and MA components

Tags: time-series, arima, stationarity

Suppose we have an $ARMA(p,q)$ model and we are checking for invertibility. Is it possible that the $ARMA(p,q)$ is invertible but the $AR(p)$ component or the $MA(q)$ component is not invertible?